# How to download the wikicode of a Wikipedia page?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki

I want to download the wikicode of [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris) with a single Web request.

Is there any better way than getting https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paris&action=edit and filtering the content of the `<textarea>`?

In particular, how to do this with the REST API?

Comment: Do you just want https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paris&action=raw?

Comment: @hsl: Yes that's it, thanks for the URL! Can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passing `action=raw` is the best way to obtain just the wikitext of a page, although it can be done with the API. See https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paris&action=raw for example and the [MediaWiki docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#Raw).

Answer (score 0):

You can export the wikicode in XML format.

Source:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Export

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Downloading_pages#Downloading the wikitext of a page